# switching images with animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview, scroll, core-animation

I'd like to have a static background image (let's imagine a model in underwear), where several images are placed in layers in front of the background. Each image in front can be switched out, from the left or right, with some animation.

So our model might start with a panama hat on her head. A gesture replaces it with a porkpie hat, another gesture places a toque. A dress on her body switches to a pant suit, then mechanic overalls. Cowboy boots to sandals to galoshes, and etc.

It seems there are many ways to do this. I could use UIScrollView, with paging enabled. There is Core Animation, with CALayers on top of the background image. Even simple UIImageViews with swipe gestures enabled, tracking coordinates of the user's finger.

Does one of these techniques stand out as being better than the others in this case? Or does it seem to you readers that each could work as well as the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say if you want a prebuild solution try OpenFlow (I'm not affiliated, just a user)

http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/

Otherwise, maybe just a UIScrollView with paging enabled would do the trick?

Comment: Thank you. This makes me realize I should edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: In the end, I did use a set of UIScrollViews with paging enabled. Easy to do (or at least, not many lines of code), but there were a number of tricky problems putting multiple scrolling pages in a single view. I did not find the Apple documentation all that clear. But thank you for pointing me in this direction!